# How can I query concurrent events, i.e. usage, in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

From my first table of events below, what query would give me my second table of usage?

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 08:42 | 08:47 |
| 08:44 | 08:50 |

| start | end | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08:42 | 08:44 | 1 |
| 08:44 | 08:47 | 2 |
| 08:47 | 08:50 | 1 |

What if any indexes should I create to speed this up?

The main thing I often need is the peak usage and when it is (i.e. max count row from above), so also is there a quicker way to get one/both of these?

Also, is it quicker to query for each second (which I can imagine how to do), e.g:

| time | count |
| --- | --- |
| 08:42 | 1 |
| 08:43 | 1 |
| 08:44 | 2 |
| 08:45 | 2 |
| 08:46 | 2 |
| 08:47 | 1 |
| 08:48 | 1 |
| 08:49 | 1 |

NB my actual starts/ends are timestamp(6) with time zone and I have thousands of records, but I hope my example above is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=afa0ae26eb5c16567d293b8a6db97ac8)

```
SELECT 
    t as start, 
    lead as "end",
    sum as count
FROM (
    SELECT
        t,
        lead(t) OVER (ORDER BY t),     -- 2a
        type,
        SUM(type) OVER (ORDER BY t)    -- 2b
    FROM (
        SELECT                         -- 1
            start as t,
            1 as type
        FROM mytable
        
        UNION 
        
        SELECT
            stop,
            -1 as type
        FROM mytable
    ) s
) s
WHERE sum > 0                          -- 3
```

1. Put all time values into one column. Add the `1` value to former `start` values and `-1` to former `end` values
2. a) put the next time values into the current record b) use cumulative `SUM()` over the newly added `1`/`-1` value. Each `start` point increased the count, each `end` value decreased it. This is your expected `count`
3. Remove all records without an interval.

---

The above only works properly if your borders are distinct. If you have interval borders at the same time point, you have to change the `UNION` into `UNION ALL` (which keeps same values) and group this result afterwards to generate for example `-2` from two `-1` values at same time slot:

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=25c2fb19757a08811e3140151a45275a)

```
SELECT 
    t as start, 
    lead as "end",
    sum as count
FROM (
    SELECT
        t,
        lead(t) OVER (ORDER BY t),
        type,
        SUM(type) OVER (ORDER BY t)
    FROM (
        SELECT
            t,
            SUM(type) AS type
        FROM (
            SELECT
                start as t,
                1 as type
            FROM mytable
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT
                stop,
                -1 as type
            FROM mytable
        ) s
        GROUP BY t
    ) s
) s
WHERE sum > 0
```